# Countdown Date/Days using Andengine

Tags: android, date, andengine, countdown

I am looking for a countdown tutorial using Andengine.This is what i need to do with app ie i need to count till specific date and when it reaches that date it must show some message and when that date passes by it must once again show countdown till that date for next year.How to implement this.i searched for various tutorials but am unable to find out.Hope someone would help me.

Update :
          clocktext = new Text(CAMERA_WIDTH/4.4f, CAMERA_HEIGHT/3.6f,this.mFont, "Hello AndEngine!", this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());

```
      Calendar thatDay = Calendar.getInstance();
      thatDay.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,30);
      thatDay.set(Calendar.MONTH,9); // 0-11 so 1 less
      thatDay.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2014);

      Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();

      //long diff = today.getTimeInMillis() - thatDay.getTimeInMillis(); //result in millis
      long diff = thatDay.getTimeInMillis()-today.getTimeInMillis(); //result in millis
      long days = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

    this.remain = days;
        if(remain<0){

      clocktext = new Text(CAMERA_WIDTH/9.8f, CAMERA_HEIGHT/1.4f,this.mFont, remain + "", this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
      }if(remain==0){
          clocktext = new Text(CAMERA_WIDTH/9.8f, CAMERA_HEIGHT/1.4f,this.mFont, "HAPPY HALLOWEEN", this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
      }if(remain>0){
          clocktext = new Text(CAMERA_WIDTH/9.8f, CAMERA_HEIGHT/1.4f,this.mFont, remain + "", this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
      }
```

Comment: just a alternative : in andengine also u can implement simple java or android countDown Timeer , or rather u can use chrometer too ..

Comment: @mtetno Thanks for the answer.How to set exact date say 30/10/Year from calendar and from current date i would like to get difference ie Days.And on reaching that date i would like to show a message and when date passes by i would like counter to start showing remaining days until next year.

Comment: @mtetno updated code which i tried.

Comment: you want only date diff not time diff right?

Comment: @mtetno Yes.Date difference

Comment: @mtetno Updated code once again.As per my given code.It does show date difference.And when i change time in system clock text doesn't capture update.I am using this code for live wallpaper.In preview mode it refresh while loading but when i set this as screen wallpaper it doesn't update

Comment: @mtetno  do you have any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Here is code snip :

```
package de.goddchen.android.andthrow.library;

import org.anddev.andengine.engine.handler.IUpdateHandler;

public class CountDownTimer implements IUpdateHandler {

    private float timerSeconds;

    private float timerInterval;

    private float lastCall;

    private boolean isRunning;

    private float timeElapsed;

    private iCountDownListener listener;

    public interface iCountDownListener {
        public void onIntervalElapsed(float timeRemaining, CountDownTimer timer);

        public void onCountDownEnded(CountDownTimer timer);
    }

    public CountDownTimer(float timerSeconds, float timerInterval,
            iCountDownListener listener) {
        this.timerInterval = timerInterval;
        this.timerSeconds = timerSeconds;
        this.listener = listener;
        this.isRunning = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
        timeElapsed += pSecondsElapsed;
        // Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "elapsed: " + timeElapsed);
        if (isRunning) {
            if (timeElapsed - lastCall > timerInterval) {
                listener.onIntervalElapsed(timerSeconds - timeElapsed, this);
                lastCall = timeElapsed;
            }
            if (timeElapsed > timerSeconds) {
                listener.onCountDownEnded(this);
                cancel();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void reset() {

    }

    public void cancel() {
        isRunning = false;
    }

}
```